# Cycles Render settings for Bake Texture for Game Assets

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine, texture-baking, lighting

here I'd like to find out how to set Bake Texture settings for baking interior with the light path in Cycles Render. I have an interior and several objects that I'd bake the texture on this scene:
[image]

As u can see, I'm using several light paths and several emission materials on a certain object. Below are my current settings for sampling and the light paths:

[image]

And also here are my node editor settings:

[image]

After I baked it, I got a terrible result like this:
[image]

There are a lot of noises, and not recommended for game assets. So what should I do to get a realistic baked texture by using cycles render to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). Your Render sample count is only at 512. Perhaps doubling it could help?

Comment: I do for 4k samples, it much better but there're still noises around